# React Native Firebase Notifications Don't Show While the User is Using the App

Tags: firebase, react-native, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase to send notifications to my React Native frontend. Notifications come through fine when the app is closed, but user's don't receive the notification while they are inside the app. How can I force the notification through every time?

Answer (score 2):

the notifications are received but not showing when the app is open (foreground) you will have to use this or similar solution to show the notification on the screen in this case.
[check this link](https://wix.github.io/react-native-notifications/docs/localNotifications/)

I have used it on android and iOS with no problems.

You can't "force" them but you can handle them